# How to bind width and height of a drawer element to the window size?

Tags: wpf, material-design

I'm using `Material Design` elements. I need to specify the width and height for `materialDesign:DrawerHost` element. I want it to cover all the window. The code is:

```
<Grid Grid.RowSpan="3">
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost x:Name="DrawerHost" Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Margin="32"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Width="auto"
        Height="auto"
        BorderThickness="2"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}"
        BottomDrawerCornerRadius="20 20 0 0"
        BottomDrawerBackground="{DynamicResource SecondaryHueLightBrush}">
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost>
</Grid>
```

I tried to use `Height="auto"` and `Width="auto"` but it does not have any effect. How can I fix it in my code?

Comment: how about `Width="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=WindowHeight}"`

Comment: @LeiYang It works but when I maximize the window, the element does not correspond to the new size. I want it to be flexible.

Comment: what about `Path=ActualWidth`

Comment: Thanks, Worked. Can you please write your answer so I can mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: done. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to Windows's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.
`auto` will often cause minimal size just to fit the content, not expanding to the containter. and even if `auto` works as expanding, the grid size is also minimal by default. So you'd rather bind directly to Window.